# Change URL on first and second clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've searched the internet and stackoverflow for how to trigger a second click function and this is what I found:

```
$('.elementclass').toggle(
function(){
   //on odd
    },
function(){
   //on even
});
```

It's perfect. Now according to this I try to change the URL of my document but something doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
$('.orderby').toggle(
function(){
      document.location.href+='?orderby='+$(this).val()+'ASC';
},
function(){
      document.location.href+='?orderby='+$(this).val()+'DESC';
});
```

where `$(this).val()` will be something like name or date...

What I want to accomplish is: on first click of a button, the URL changes to http://blablabla/page.php?orderby=nameASC and then on the second click, the URL changes to http://blablabla/page.php?orderby=nameDESC.

So what's wrong with my code?

**I don't want to refresh the page when user click on button, I just want to add some (one in this case) parameters that can take whit $_GET later but on same page.document.URL can be update whit +=?orderby=nameASC on first click and on second click +=?orderby=nameASC need to be remove and document.URL update whit +=?orderby=nameDESC.**

Comment: **window**.location? Also, if you change the URL on the first click your browser is gonna navigate away from the page and the 2nd callback won't execute

Comment: Is this for sorting? Seriously?

Comment: what is wrong with that @MilkyWayJoe? Perfectly acceptable if the sorting is done one the server.

Comment: Then why go to all this trouble in JS if you are gonna hit the server anyway? I mean I love client scripting but sometimes there's no point. Why not use normal HTML markup with a proper query and handle the toggle of the sort order on the server? Then echo the link with the other query string... Seriously... If you're not doing it asynchronously, just do it normal

Comment: True. You could change the button on the server to reflect the state of the sorting. Oh well. At least the code will be prepared for ajaxing the result in :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You page changes so the script is loaded again.
You need to test what url you have

**Updated to handle different orderby values**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.orderby').click(
    function(){
     var srch = location.search;
     if (srch) srch = srch.substring(1); // lose the ?
     var val = $(this).val();

     if (srch.indexOf(val+"ASC")!=-1)
       srch = srch.replace(val+"ASC",val+"DESC");
     else if (srch.indexOf(val+"DESC")!=-1)
       srch = srch.replace(val+"DESC",val+"ASC");
       else if (!srch || srch.indexOf("orderby")!=-1) {
         // if srch was empty or contained another value than this'
         srch ='orderby='+$(this).val()+'ASC'; 
       }
     var loc = (location.search)?location.href.split("?")[0]:location.href;
     window.location = loc + "?"+srch;
  });
});
```

PS: document.location.href was deprecated many many years ago. Use document.URL or window.location.href instead

PPS: As MilkyWayJoe correctly stated - why bother - if the page is loaded from the server into the current page and not into an iframe or ajaxed, then set the value of the button on the server and have a normal link - that would make it work even when JS was turned off

---

**UPDATE2**

IF you use AJAX you want to do stuff like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (location.hash.indexOf(....) {
    // find the element which is mentioned in the orderby and click it
    var $elem = ....
    $elem.click(); // or trigger
  }

  $('.orderby').toggle(
    function(){
      $("#someLabel").html("DESC");
      var orderBy = $(this).val()+'ASC';
      location.hash = orderBy; // now URL will be ...#nameASC
      $("#content").load('soneserverprocess?orderby='+orderBy);
  },
  function(){
      $("#someLabel").html("ASC");
      var orderBy = $(this).val()+'DESC';
      location.hash = orderBy; // now URL will be ...#nameDESC
      $("#content").load('someserverprocess?orderby='+orderBy);
  });
});
```

If you want to use in-browser sorting, use one of these

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/02/jquery-filter-sort-plugins.html

and have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (location.hash.indexOf(....) {
    // find the element which is mentioned in the orderby and click it
    var $elem = ....
    $elem.click(); // or trigger
  }

  $('.orderby').toggle(
    function(){
      $("#someLabel").html("DESC");
      var orderBy = $(this).val()+'ASC';
      location.hash = orderBy; // now URL will be ...#nameASC
      $("#content").sort(....); // depending on plugin
    },
    function(){
      $("#someLabel").html("ASC");
      var orderBy = $(this).val()+'DESC';
      location.hash = orderBy; // now URL will be ...#nameDESC
      $("#content").sort(....); // depending on plugin
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't want to refresh the page when user click on button, I just want to add some (one in this case) parameters that can take whit $_GET later but on same page.And by the way your code doesn't work if I am on http://blablabla/page.php on first click he add me an ? and on second click he add me one more ? so the URL become after the two clicks http://blablabla/page.php/??. And I want this work whenever I press the button (on odd and on even clicks).

Comment: Changing the location of the page will necessarily cause a page refresh (except in the special case of changing the hash, which doesn't apply here).  What you want is an Ajax call that rewrites your table with data fetched from the server: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started.

Comment: @George02 - the way you phrased your question, the solution is to reload the page. If you want to use Ajax, then the solution is completely different

Comment: so @mplungjan there is no way to add parameters to URL whithout using AJAX and reload the page?

Comment: Only changes to the HASH (#...) which would not sort the data if the sorted data comes from the server. If all the data is already IN the browser you can of course use things like sortable.js and change the url by changing the hash. Is ALL the data in the browser?

Comment: @mplungajan Truly amazing now I don't need to use hash ! Thank you ! You are the best for me!

Comment: You could use it if you want the sort order to be bookmarkable

Answer (score 1):

When you navigate to a new page (or reload the current page) your Javascript execution environment is reset.  This means that the `toggle` function is only ever going to execute once per page, so the second function is never used.

You're better off doing something like:

```
$('.orderby').click(function() {
    if(/ASC$/.test(window.location.href) {
        // switch to DESC
    } else {
        // switch to ASC
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, as I posted. And it is document.URL or window.location.href and not document.location.href (deprecated)

Comment: I'd never seen document.location used before; now I know why.  Corrected to be standards-compliant.

Comment: I'am not sure I understant. What means /ASC$/ and whit what value need to be initialize.I don't want to refresh the page when user click on button, I just want to add some (one in this case) parameters that can take whit $_GET later but on same page.

Comment: `/ASC$/` is a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) that is used to test if the URL ends with ASC.  As I commented under @mplungjan's answer, you almost certainly want Ajax to solve this problem. If you don't know Ajax, please learn how it works, because learning it will dramatically change the way you think about Web app architecture.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, the page will <s>get reloaded</s> be loaded on every click and so as the libraries. Only the first handler in the toggle function will be executed <s>in that case</s> all the time. So it is going to be always `ASC`.

You probably need a simple click handler and inside the handler look for `window.location.search` has `ASC` or `DES`.

Comment: Would really appreciate if the downvoter can leave a comment So I can learn from my mistakes.. simply downvoting doesn't really help. The purpose of downvoting is to improve the answer or point out problems..

Comment: Perhaps because it is more a comment than a solution... I also was downvoted for no apparent and no commented reason

Comment: @mplungjan The second part was the clue to the answer.. tbh I post code and demo in most of my answers.. unfortunately I had to leave this in the middle and when I came back there were 3 down votes.. Downvoting a bad answer is ok, but leaving a comment would really make us understand why and correct the answer. Most times I end up deleting it if it is duplicating someone else answer.